# Change the name of DB Facade

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I'm using Lumen with an existing PHP application.

There's a conflict in the global namespace.  The existing app also have a DB class in the global namespace which is conflicting with the Lumen's DB class.

```
// in vendor/laravel/lument-framework/src/Appliction.php

public function withFacades()
{
    Facade::setFacadeApplication($this);

    if (! static::$aliasesRegistered) {
        static::$aliasesRegistered = true;

        class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\App', 'App');
        class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth', 'Auth');
        class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus', 'Bus');
        class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB', 'DB');
        ...
    }
}
```

If I change class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB', 'LumenDB'); solves the problem for me, but I don't want to edit code in the vendor folder.

Is there anyway I can change it programmatically?

Comment: I am not familiar with Lumen, but shouldn't you be changing the alias name in app/config/app.php and not the vendor files. Otherwise, you could always alias your DB class instead.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary For performance reasons Lumen doesn't have any configuration files except for `.env`. So your second suggestion is possibly the only way of handling this.

Answer (score 1):

Alright.  I think I have a workaround for now.

In the bootstrap/app.php uncomment or remove this lines

```
// $app->withFacades();
```

and replace with.

```
class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\App', 'App');
class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth', 'Auth');
class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Bus', 'Bus');
class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB', 'LumenDB');
...
...
class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator', 'Validator');
```

So we will register the facades manually instead of calling the withFacades() function.

Comment: Yep, that'll work fine and I think it's the best option.

Comment: It's the simplest yet fastest solution.

Answer (score 1):

The correct method in newer versions of Laravel/Lumen is to pass an array of "user aliases" as the second argument to the `$app->withFacades()` method.

```
$app->withFacades(
    true, // $aliases parameter set to true (default)
    [
    'Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB' => 'LumenDB',
    ] // array of $userAliases
);
```